# c++ - Converting raw data to type - odd behavior

Tags: c++, memory, casting

I found a behavior I can't explain in cpp.

If I cast a `char*` to `uint32_t`, it prints gibberish, but if the same data is `memcpy()`'ed to a `uint32_t`, the printout is fine.

Can someone explain to me why this is happening?

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main()
{
    
    unsigned char a[8]; //some generic byte storage
    memset(a,0xFF,8);   //setting
    memset(a,0x00,4);   //zeroing the lower-half 

    
    printf("A %x\n", (uint32_t)a); //prints A 7946a7b0 (expected 00000000)
    
    uint32_t b = 0;
    memcpy(&b, a+2, 4);
    
    printf("B %x\n",b ); // prints B ffff0000 (correct)

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _undefined behavior_??

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: You are printing the address of `a` cast to a `uint32_t`.  Try `*(uint32_t*)a`.

Comment: `a` is an array which decays to a pointer to `char` so cast to `uint32_t` gives you half of the address of `a` (assuming 64 bit platform). Also your attempt is UB so really funny things can happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the 1st `printf()` statement, you are allowing `a` to *decay* into a `unsigned char*` pointer to its 1st element, and then you are casting that pointer itself to an integer, so you end up printing out the numeric value of the memory address which the pointer is holding.

In order to access the `uint32_t` data that is being pointing at, you need to cast the `unsigned char*` pointer to a `uint32_t*` pointer first and then deference it, eg:

```
printf("A %x\n", *(uint32_t*)a);
```

In the second `printf()` statement, you are printing out the value of a `uint32_t` which you copied from the memory address that `a+2` is pointing at.